Are these filters suitable for this application?
I want to use the ADF4350 as a local oscillator and I want it to sweep as fast as possible from a start frequency A to the end frequency B the issue is the span is large and for that i have to use a large loop bandwidth which should not exceed 1/10 of the phase detector or 1/5 at max for stability. Now for me to use a large bandwidth i need a good loop filter and i need your opinion.
Are those listed filters suitable for the task? And which one of them is better?
The frequency reference will be a TCXO equal to 10 time the bandwidth, and the phase detector is equal to the frequency reference. the loop bandwidth is the max bandwidth of the filter.

LTC1560-1
LT1567
LT1568
LTC6603

Edit:  some members suggest to stick to a passive 3rd order filter and that an active filter is not necessary as this what is dictated in the datasheet and/or ADIsimPLL. In this document at figure 20 shows/proves the effects of high order filter were the phase margin is getting wider and wider as the bandwidth is getting larger which is my goal.
The filters i have listed promises a tightned matching phase .


Are those listed filters suitable for the task? And wich one of them is better?

The best solution would be to use a passive 3rd order filter as shown in the datasheet. An active filter is unnecessary and the listed examples are not suited anyway. The filter can be designed and simulated with "ADIsimPLL" from Analog Devices.
https://www.analog.com/en/lp/resources/adisimpll.html
---- EDIT ----

some members suggest to stick to a passive 3rd order filter and that an active filter is not necessary as this what is dictated in the datasheet and/or ADIsimPLL.

The datasheet doesn't dictate anything. A passive (3rd oder) filter is the obvious, simple, low noise solution considering the max. level of the VCO tuning voltage.
You can of course increase the loop bandwidth, within reason. The question is if you should do it. The answer for the ADF4350 is no.
A large loop bandwidth means that a lot of the internally generated noise, like that from the SD-modulator, would be introduced inside the loop modulating the VCO.
The lock time of the VCO is limited, even with large loop bandwidths, fast lock and cycle slip reduction enabled. Increasing loop bandwidth has only a minor impact in lock time. For lock times below 100...200us consider another PLL chip.

In this document at figure 20 shows/proves the effects of high order filter were the phase margin is getting wider and wider as the bandwidth is getting larger which is my goal.

I can't see that in Fig. 20. I have no clue what you mean with phase margin getting "wide".
Fig 14 shows that the phase noise of the reference (122.88MHz) and the open loop phase noise of the VCXO (also 122.88MHz) intersect at about 80Hz, which leads to a good starting point for the PLL bandwidth. Later it was determined, through tuning and measurement, that the optimal loop bandwidth in this case is 40Hz. Fig. 20 shows that inside the bandwidth of the PLL the noise from the VCXO, close to the carrier, is suppressed and well behaved following the somewhat better phase noise of the reference.

The filters i have listed promises a tightned matching phase .

Most of the (specialized) filter chips you listed are extremely noisy and have no place as a PLL filter. If you want an active filter at all cost, choose a good, low noise op amp.

I don't know why you think that a 3rd order filter is the best solution  except it "shown in datasheet" as all of us know going up in order filters increases the phase shift  which mean it slow down the lock time and on the other hand in datasheet or with ADIsimPLL they dont go above KHz bandwidth .

A passive filter is a obvious, low noise solution. I don't understand why you are deliberately trying to introduce additional noise from an active component into the loop if there is no reason to do so. The tuning voltage for the VCO(s) does not exceed the supply voltage of the chip which means a passive filter is sufficient for the job. It is up to you to design the PLL filter for the loop bandwidth and phase margin you need.
